# Can Netflix's Eureka be used outside AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, netflix, service-discovery

I'm looking for a good discovery service to use in a growing, privately-hosted microservice architecture.

[Netflix's Eureka](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-at-a-glance) looks promising. It says it is "primarily used in the AWS cloud for locating services", but I can't figure out whether it can be used outside AWS or not. A cursory glance at the POMs revealed that there are AWS dependencies included in the project.

Can Eureka (or a useful subset of it) be used outside AWS as a discovery service?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, It can be used outside AWS. One just needs to change a few configuration options. Specifically, the dataCenterInfo option to let the server know that its in a non-AWS environment.

Have a look at https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Configuring-Eureka to see how this can be done.